# how i can solve equation No (8) using the quadratic formula

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

[Maximum area of a triangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/177213/maximum-area-of-a-triangle)

So in the answer of this question i want to understand two point
first one is this how he change 
\begin{align}
(a^2+b^2-2ab\cos(\angle AOB))=a^2b^2\sin^2(\angle AOB)\\
\end{align}
the second point and it's so important to me is how he solve (8) for cos(∠AOB) using the quadratic formula to get this equation

\begin{align}
\cos(\angle AOB)=\frac{p^2-\sqrt{(p^2-c^2a^2)(p^2-b^2c^2)}}{abc^2}\
\end{align}

i would really someone to help me here
thanks

Comment: Using the identity $sin^2 x +cos^2 x = 1$ you can get an equation that is quadratic with respect to cosine.

Comment: \begin{align}
(a^2+b^2-2ab\cos(\angle AOB)) = a^2b^2\sin^2(\angle AOB)\\
\end{align}  how here he use  sin2x+cos2x=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He's using two different formulas for the area of a triangle and equating them. One formula is $$\text{Area} = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \text{base} \cdot \text{height}$$
or $$|\triangle AOB|= \frac{1}{2}|\overline{AB}||\overline{OF}|\tag {1}$$
The other formula is the [side-angle-side formula](http://www.mathwarehouse.com/trigonometry/area/side-angle-side-triangle.php) which gives $$|\triangle AOB|= \frac{1}{2}ab\sin(\angle AOB)\tag{2}$$
He then inserts formulas for $|\overline{AB}|$ and $|\overline{OF}|$ in equation $(1)$, squares both sides and replaces $\sin^2(\angle AOB)$ with ($1-\cos^2(\angle AOB)$) to get $$(a^2+b^2-2ab\cos(\angle AOB))(p/c)^2 = a^2b^2(1-\cos^2(\angle AOB))$$
The above is a quadratic equation with the variable $\cos(\angle AOB)$, which he then solves.